# Код заменяет не два значения, как по заданию, так ли это?

Tags: python

Преподаватель сказал что код меняет больше двух значений, хотя по заданию нужно два, но я вижу что он меняет два - максимальное и минимальное. Что не так?

Задание:
Заполните список вещественных чисел размерности [1..N],
используя генератор случайных чисел .
Границу списка N задавать как константу.
Напечатать полученный список в текстовый файл outfile.
Поменять местами наибольший и наименьший элементы.
Напечатать полученный список в ТОТ ЖЕ файл.

```
import random

print ('граница списка: ')
V = int(input())
gg = [random.uniform(1, V) for i in range (V)]
print (gg)

with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(' '.join(map(str, gg)))

max_gg = max(gg)
min_gg = min(gg)

for i in range(len(gg)):
  if gg[i] == max_gg:
    gg[i] = min_gg
  elif gg[i] == min_gg:
    gg[i] = max_gg

with open('newfile.txt', 'a') as f:
  f.write('\n')
  f.write(str(gg))
```

Comment: а если два раза встретится максимальный элемент?

Comment: Что будет на примере: `[1, 1, 2]`?  Будут изменены три элемента массива. А нужно два.

Comment: Ну вообще говоря задачка по поводу нескольких максимумов и минимумов не обговаривает какое должно быть поведение.

Comment: @CrazyElf, преподаватель - пурист. "наибольший и наименьший элементы" действительно по правилам русского языка говорят о двух, иначе было бы "наибольшие и наименьшие". Но вполне себе представляю, как автор приходит к другому преподавателю с решением, как у меня ниже, а тот говорит, что это глупо - поменять только два элемента, а не все одинаковые. Иными словами- всегда надо уточнять, что в реальности нужно Заказчику, а не просто, что в ТЗ:-)

Comment: @Сергей В реальной жизни бывает ещё хуже - заказчик может и сам не знать, что ему на самом деле нужно ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, читаем PMI - "Agile практическое руководство" (если не ошибаюсь, это или там или у Эрика Риса, впрочем PMI на его идеях сильно "сидит"): "Мы узнаем, что надо Заказчику, когда принесём ему работающий образец, который его устроит" (за 100% точность цитаты не ручаюсь, но смысл такой).

Comment: @Сергей Есть и другой вариант - убедить заказчика, что мы написали именно то, что ему на самом деле нужно )

Comment: Я вообще-то имел в виду, рассказать ему, что стало на практике понятно, как работать с Заказчиком, чтобы  он погордился, как он умело развивает студентов и оценил такого сметливого студента. А не смущать его незнакомым ему, возможно, словом:-)

Comment: он знает это слово, по факту у него достаточно черный юмор, и полагаю, что всё таки он пурист). Так что всё в порядке, а про заказчика, было бы слишком заумно с моей стороны).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачка с подначкой:-) Стало интересно проверить - так что сделал сам (вы не просили, но тогда для базы знаний, если вам не надо).
Циклы тут не нужны, раз препод такой хитрый, и надо только по одному числу менять максимальному и минимальному, а не все.

Вместо:

```
for i in range(len(gg)):
  if gg[i] == max_gg:
    gg[i] = min_gg
  elif gg[i] == min_gg:
    gg[i] = max_gg
```

Ставим:

```
# ищем индексы макс и мин элементов и меняем элементы местами
max_index = gg.index(max_gg)
min_index = gg.index(min_gg)
gg[max_index], gg[min_index] = gg[min_index], gg[max_index]
```

Comment: попробуем, послезавтра пара), отпишусь

Comment: Рекомендую почитать выше комментарии к вопросу (про Заказчика) и применить соответственно к ситуации (например, цитату) с серьёзным видом, если у препода чувство юмора есть, или практического применения программирования к работе с  Заказчиком, то может оценить:-) В конце концов, все это обучение нужно, в основном, чтобы зарабатывать деньги, делая людям то, что им нужно:-)

Comment: сказал - "всё работает, поздравляю"
я добавил - "вы пурист?"
он - "нуууу, нет, наверное.."
)))